# Python Pandas data frame to a Temp Table in PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, temp-tables

I have a Pandas data frame `df` of the form:

```
ID   X    Y    Z
1    0.5  0.6  0.1
2    0.6  0.9  0.2
3    0.1  0.6  0.3
etc.
```

The data frame contains about 3,000,000 row entries. I am trying to write this data frame as a **Temp Table** into a local PostgreSQL database. I would like the temporary table to disappear when the connection is closed. Also, it should only be visible to the current connection to the source. An equivalent function in R is the [copy_to()](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/copy_to.html) function.

In order to accomplish this in Python, I have the following code:

```
import psycopg2

conn = get_reporting_db_conn('localhost')
cur = conn.cursor()
rows = zip(df.ID, df.X, df.Y, df.Z)
cur.execute("""CREATE TEMP TABLE Scores(ID INTEGER, X FLOAT, Y FLOAT, Z FLOAT) ON COMMIT DROP""")
cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO Scores (ID, X, Y, Z) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)""", rows)

conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

The code works, although the `cur.executemany(...)` line takes too long to execute (inserting entries line-by-line). Is there any other (faster) way to write a Pandas data frame as a **Temp Table** into a local PostgreSQL database without it becoming a permanent table?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?